# Funny if condition in C

Tags: c++, c, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm trying to understand some C/C++ code that was written **quick and dirty** like 6-10 years ago.

What does this if-expression mean ?

```
int s_adr, e_adr, empf_adr;
// ...

if (success == OK &&
    (s_adr & 0x1f) == empf_adr &&
    (e_adr & 0x20) &&
    (s_adr & 0x20)
    )
```

Is `(e_adr & 0x20)` the same as `((e_adr & 0x20) == 1)` ? Or how do I have to understand that ? I guess this is probably a stupid question when you know C and C++ very well. But I don't.

Comment: This is not C++ code. There is at least an operator missing between `(e_adr & 0x20)` and `(s_adr & 0x20)`.

Comment: More like (e_adr & 0x20) is equivalent to ((e_adr & 0x20) !=0)

Comment: That is really basic C, though. true == non-zero

Comment: @wolfgang Sorry I removed comments and killed the `&&` :)

Comment: I'm probably somewhat evil when it comes to optimising: `(e_adr & s_adr & 0x20)`

Comment: @MSalters, I prefer the original because the behaviour is actually different if the `0x20` is replaced by something with more than one bit set; and so the original documents the intent better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` is a bit operation, where as `&&` is a boolean operation.

For example, the following is obvious;

```
if (a && b) ...
```

However, the following is not:

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
if (a & b) ...
if (a && b) ...
```

These two if checks give different results.  Boolean operations in C assume `false` is `0` and `true` is anything other than `0`.  Thus, boolean operation `&&` in the above code will result in `true`.

The bit operation `&`, however does a bitwise AND of the two parameters.  1 in binary is 0001, and 2 in binary is 0010.  Bitwise AND does the following

```
    0001
AND 0010
    ----
    0000
```

Each digit is ANDed to make the result.

A bitwise OR (`|`) of 0001 and 0010 would result in 0011.

Comment: I thought `0 = false, 1 = true`. Now I see `0 = false, (!=0) = true`. Thats good to know thanks!

Comment: @mini-me In some languages, that is correct.  In C, however, it is not.  Minor thing that most people overlook!

Comment: @mini-me: it's actually a bit more complex because the transitions are not symmetric. `0 <-> false` is symmetric, however `(!=0) -> true` and `true -> 1`. Boolean conversion is lossy :)

Comment: @Trenin What's not correct? In C, logical operators treat all nonzero values as true, don't they?

Comment: @TannerSwett You are right - in C non-zero means true.  I was stating that OPs original statement (`0 = false, 1 = true`) was not correct in C.  Probably should have been clearer.

Answer (score 9):

No these two conditions are not the same. `(e_adr & 0x20)` is the same as `(e_adr & 0x20) != 0`(and in fact if the value of this expression is not zero it can only be `0x20`). Effectively this checks if the 6-th least significant bit of `e_adr` is non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

(e_adr & 0x20) means you are checking 6th bit from right of e_adr is set to 1 or not. That is not of course equivalent to 1. For example, say e_adr is 0x4430, (e_adr & 0x20) becomes 0x0020 (in a if condition that is interpreted as true or 1). However, if e_adr is 0x4440, (e_adr & 0x20) becomes 0x0000 (in a if condition that is interpreted as false or 0).

Comment: It might be possible that OP is not aware of bit operations like & and is confusing it with logical operation &&.

Answer (score 2):

```
e_adr & 0x20
```

is equivalent to

```
( e_adr & 0x20 ) == 0x20
```

that is this expression checks whether bit 5 is set on in e_adr (I am counting bits from LSB starting from 0)

I mean this expression is used in if statements that is relative to your code snip.:)

Comment: `e_adr & 0x20 == 0x20` is wrong. It's `(e_adr & 0x20) != 0` actually.

Comment: @Frank Bollack Are you sure?:) I mean using the expression in the if statement

Comment: Umm... it is correct in terms of the *logical* condition is checking (i.e. what could you replace (e_addr & 0x20) with to achieve the same result), but ((e_adr & 0x20) !=0) is a more accurate representation of what is being really checked.

Comment: Really? Whats the difference?

Comment: @S.C.Madsen `e_adr & 0x20` is evaluated and then considered in a boolean context (i.e. 0 is false, anything else is true). `e_addr & 0x20 == 0x20`, first the `e_addr & 0x20` is evaluated and then compared numerically with 0x20, this results in a boolean result.

Comment: @jsantander The both are equivalent. Moreover my interpretation is more clear for readers of the code. As for Frank Bollack  then its purpose is simply to down vote the correct answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I agree they're equivalent, but they're not the same.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I removed the down vote as the result of both expressions is equivalent. But I doubt that `e_addr & 0x20 == 0x20` is more clear to someone who is not familiar with bit operators and expression evaluation

Comment: @Frank Bollack Consider for example expression if ( Color & Red == Red ) with if ( Color & Red ). in my opinion the first expression is more clear.

Comment: @jsantander I just checked: `((0x20 & 0x20) == 0x20)` is true and `(0x20 & 0x20 == 0x20)` is false. `0x20 == 0x20` is evaluated first.

Comment: @mini-me A good remark! I often make such a mistake when & and == is used together.:)

Comment: @mini-me, there is no evaluation order defined; but the operator precedence in `a & b == c` is `a & (b == c)`.  A mnemonic I use to remember this is that `&` and `&&` have the same precedence (same goes for `|` and `||` etc.) , and the logical variants have sensible precedence.